# How to make a service Android Programming

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I am trying to start and close a service. My service is Logs.

```
package com.example.textsmslock;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
public class Logs extends Service
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
     @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStart(intent, startId);
            System.out.println("LOGS STARTED");
            Log.d("TAG", "FirstService started");
        }
       @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
        }
}
```

The activity calling it is ConfirmPin. Logs is being called in a function.

```
// imports...
// public class...

public void ConfirmingPin()
{   
    if(pinCorrect) 
    {
        startService(new Intent("com.example.textsmslock.Logs"));
    }
}
```

Here is my AndridManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.textsmslock"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ConfirmPin"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_confirm_pin" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.textsmslock.ConfirmPin" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".Logs"/>
</application>
```

The logcat says:

> Unable to start service Intent { act=com.example.textsmslock.Logs }: not found

Does anyone know why I am unable to start the service intent?

Comment: @rekire I agree with most of your edit, but LogCats should be formatted in code blocks not quotes. Quote blocks ignore the line breaks in multi-line LogCats, making the stack trace _very_ difficult to read.

Comment: @Sam normally I do so too, but not for a one liner.

Comment: @rekire Why use two standards? Beside I've grown to like the technicolor LogCat. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IntentFilter in your Activity's manifest doesn't seem right, try:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

And start the Service:

```
startService(new Intent(this, Logs.class));
```

(You posted this a few minutes ago with a different LogCat and that error pointed me straight to this. You deleted the question before I could post an answer though...)

Comment: Yeah I thought I had figured it out, but I didn't. Your answer worked. Thank-You so much!